# Categories as Breadcrumbs

Tags: categories

I have a site setup using a single article detail page for multiple channels. Each channel has a different category group and I need to output the categories as breadcrumbs

so it would ideally look something like this

category 1 > sub category (if exists) > entry title

Different category fields include:

- `businessIntelCategories`
- `learnCategories`
- `trainingCategories`
- `savingsCategories`

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Does each section include a category field, which the entry author uses to associate categories with an entry?

Comment: Yes it does and each section has a different category field

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just output the selected categories via category field?

Comment: Each channel using the template has a different category field and there are several channels.. I guess I can set up a conditional based on the channel name.

Comment: Unless you're following a naming convention which allows you to divine the field name based on the section or URL, a map or conditional is the way to go.